# Facebook tutorial projects don't work for me, return "undefined"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm new to developing for Facebook. I'm actually writing an app for a university course.

I followed the tutorials on the developer website, and they originally worked like a charm. I used the example which produced a login with Facebook button, and another page which would retrieve information from the logged in user and display it on the page.

I left it for a couple of weeks to work on other commitments, now this code doesn't work. Whereas before it would list the profile picture, name, email etc. Now it just says undefined. The only thing I could put it down to was that I had been using something which had been depreciated, since I'd now switched over to the timeline for my Facebook account (however why would the original example I used still be the first set of tutorials on the developer website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).

I also went to the Open Graph page on the developer website, they have a tutorial there which just displays a picture of a cookie and then adds the app to your timeline (I'm sure you're all familiar with it). That doesn't work either! It just brings up a blank box which immediately vanishes (doesn't ask me to authorise anything) and doesn't add anything to my timeline.

I've tried looking at my app settings but I can't see anything odd.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using some deprecated functions.

First thing to do is to make sure you have an application created on facebook, and that the site URL on the settings of the application is the site that you are writing your application (example: http://locahost/application_name). Also, take note of the application id  (you can find all these settings on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

Now that you got this, here is working example for extracting information for your user (replace "YOUR_APP_ID" with your application ID:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/default.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.1.8.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/default.js'></script>
                <script language="JavaScript"> 
                    function get_feed()
                    {
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                          alert(response.name);
                        });
                    }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="fb-root"></div> 
            <div id="login"></div> 
            <div id="test"></div> 
            <div id="stream"></div> 
            <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
            <script> 
            FB.init({
                appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies 
                xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
                oauth  : true
              });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
              window.location.reload();
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status == "connected") {
                // logged in and connected user, now get the facebook info
                get_feed();
                document.getElementById('login').innerHTML
                  ='<a href="#" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout fom Facebook</a><br/>';
              } else {
                document.getElementById('login').innerHTML
                  ='<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200"' 
                  + ' max-rows="1" perms="user_about_me, user_likes, friends_likes, read_stream, publish_stream">'
                  + '</fb:login-button>';
                FB.XFBML.parse();
              }
            });
            </script> 
        </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.